# Python 3.5 async keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-pulsar

I am currently looking into [`pulsar`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pulsar) for an asynchronous HTTP client.

The following example is in the docs:

```
from pulsar.apps import http

async with http.HttpClient() as session:
    response1 = await session.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')
    response2 = await session.get('https://api.github.com/emojis.json')
```

but when I try to execute it I get

```
async with http.HttpClient() as session:
         ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It looks like the `async` keyword is not recognized. I am using Python 3.5.

**Working example:**

```
import asyncio

from pulsar.apps.http import HttpClient

async def my_fun():
                    async with HttpClient() as session:
                        response1 = await session.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')
                        response2 = await session.get('https://api.github.com/emojis.json')

                    print(response1)
                    print(response2)


loop  =  asyncio.get_event_loop() 
loop.run_until_complete(my_fun())
```

Comment: Are you absolutely _certain_ you're using python 3.5?

Comment: $ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23)

Comment: Try `from pulsar.apps.http import HttpClient` and `async with HttpClient()` to see if the error changes.

Comment: What is the exact command that triggers the above error?

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson i tried as suggested, get the same error
async wit**h** HttpClient() as session:

i marked where the ^ is positioned

Comment: @Markus Please show how is this app started, e.g. `python3 ./app.py` or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can only use `async with` inside a [coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#coroutines), so you have to do this

```
from pulsar.apps.http import HttpClient
import pulsar

async def my_fun():
    async with HttpClient() as session:
        response1 = await session.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')
        response2 = await session.get('https://api.github.com/emojis.json')
    return response1, response2 

loop  =  pulsar.get_event_loop() 
res1, res2 = loop.run_until_complete(my_fun()) 
print(res1)
print(res2)
```

internally pulsar use asyncio, so you don't have to import it explicitly to use it, use it through pulsar

---

as a side note, if you upgrade to [python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep530) you can use async list/set/etc comprehension

```
from pulsar.apps.http import HttpClient
import pulsar

async def my_fun():
    async with HttpClient() as session:
        urls=['https://github.com/timeline.json','https://api.github.com/emojis.json']
        return [ await session.get(url) for url in urls]

loop  =  pulsar.get_event_loop() 
res1, res2 = loop.run_until_complete(my_fun()) 
print(res1)
print(res2)
```

Comment: i added a solution which is working, is there a way to do this without the asyncio event loop, or is this the correct way?

Comment: if I understand it correctly, they are [intended](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-492-coroutines-with-async-and-await-syntax) for use with [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html#module-asyncio), but any other library that support coroutines should work just fine, I think...

Comment: also you can use get_event_loop through pulsar